# Why are there only 2 white wires in my celling outlet box for me to install celling fan and light?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I am replacing the celling fan/light in my kitchen and when I removed the old one I didn't pay attention as I was unhooking the wires, but when I went to install the new one realized that the only 2 wires I have comming out of my celling are 2 white wires... Now what am I suoposed to hook my black/blue , and my green ground wires to ? [image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the white wires? It would be very unusual (and likely not code-compliant) to have two single white wires running to switch and/or panel. But you might have a 2-wire white **cord** which would also not be code-compliant but would be a different type of problem. Do you see only loose wires or do you see an actual junction box?

Comment: Just a moment and I will run in and take picture

Comment: I'm sorry I went back and took hanging bracket down and when I did so i realized that there are black wires up in the box that are wire nutted together but they were not used in the old celling fan/light only the 2 white wires were used.....so how do i install this new calling fan that has black, blue, white, and green wires ??  ANY AND ALL suggestions are GREATLY APPRECIATED

Comment: Those definitely look like "real wires" and not a cord stuck inside a junction box. So I don't have an answer. One of the pros will likely come along and hopefully figure it out.

Comment: Do you have a voltage-detector or multimeter you can use?

Comment: Yes I do have a voltage detector

Answer (score 1):

### Stop.   Your box is not rated for a fan.

You cannot simply put a fan on that junction box. The vibration will tear it out of the ceiling.

You may be able to resolve it by mounting a purely physical fan mount right next to it, which is fan rated, and using this junction box only to bring electrical (not carry its weight).

Once that's resolved...

### Light + fan on one switch

You don't have enough wires to control fan and light separately.  You must join the black and blue wires to each other, and connect them to a point to be determined.

Take ground to the screw in the back left of the junction box.

You have two cables coming into the box with a black and white in each.  One of the cables is the supply power, and black is hot and white is neutral. The other cable is a **switch loop**, and it is wired with black as always-hot and white as switched-hot.

Pause here and identify which cable is which.  Code requires the switch loop use the white wire for *always-hot*, it must be marked with tape or paint (on both ends) to designate that it is not a neutral.

Get a non-contact voltage tester and unhook all 4 wires (non-grounds) and turn the power on. One of the 4 wires will be hot, it will be a black, and that cable is **supply**.  The other cable is switch loop.  Mark the white, and join it to the supply black and push it into the back of the box.   Now the remaining wires will be white and black, and those colors will be valid.

From there it is straightforward; lamp black+blue to black, and lamp white to white.

### All singing, all dancing on the wires you have

For this you need smart switch tech, and a module that sits up in the fan rose.  The module connects separately to fan blue and black, power, switch loop, etc.  Then either a companion (matching) smart switch is installed in the switch box, or the switch is wired to control light only and a remote is used for the fan.  The instructions will say how to wire it.

Comment: If you don't figure out which is what, there's a 50% chance you'll have live threads on the light sockets. Color is arbitrary; what a conductor does, is not.

Comment: 2 remaining fixture wires and hook then to the whites ?? Are you taking take the black to one white and the blue to the other ??

Comment: @Zapped Whoops, forgot about that.  Black+blue must go to the same place because you don't have enough wires to separately control fan and light.

Comment: Harper your answer is correct .But he can not add a fan to that box at all. Check it out.

Comment: @RobertMoody good catch, somehow *we all* missed that...

Comment: Add it to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is a switch loop one of the whites are hot. Take a meter check voltage to ground on each white wire to find hot. Re,id wire black. Not enough wires to make both run separate . If you have pull chains on fan , splice black ,blue together. Both will run on switch and can use pull chains to make separate. You can not mount a fan in that box. That is a metal box old worked in on straps to boot. Will rip out of ceiling in time . Need a  old work fan rated box and they make one with arms that crank into frame work.